# How is NSData stored in .plists?

Tags: ios, plist, nsdata

I store a small PNG in a .plist.

When I open it in Xcode, the value of *icone* looks like classic NSData:

[image: Opened as .plist]

But when I open it as source code, here it is:

```
<key>icone</key>
<data>YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUINDVUJHRvcFgkb2JqZWN0 [...]
```

Hence my question : as it is not stored as NSData on the disk, how is this stored ? Base64?

Comment: if you are convert image to data or string to data it showing like , it is correct , what the problem u faced,

Comment: what do you mean by "really"? Is any of the ways it is stored is "unreal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode you see the hex representation of the `NSData`.

In the actual plist file you are seeing the base 64 encoded representation of the data.

Neither of these matter. In your code you simply do:

```
NSData *iconData = plistArray[0][@"icone"];
```

Comment: Alright, that's what I wanted to know ! I didn't find it in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html). Where did you get that ?

Comment: Curiosity, what would be the benefit to store it as Base64 ? It increases the size AFAIK, and the hex representation could be stored as is I guess.